# Selecting columns based on missing values in each row

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to know (for each row) which columns any NA in my data falls under. The goal is to create a new column/variable that lists the names of the columns the data shows NA for, for that particular row, preferably using dplyr.

Using this mock data,

```
data = tibble(var_1 = c(NA, 4, 5, 6, 7), var_2 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8), var_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 5))
```

I'd like to create the missing_col column:

```
  var_1 var_2 var_3       missing_col
1    NA     4    NA  "var_1", "var_3"             
2     4     5    NA           "var_3"
3     5     6    NA           "var_3"
4     6     7     3                NA
5     7     8     5                NA
```

My approach thus far has been to use the rowwise() function in conjunction with mutate and a nested select_if() and a function. However, none of the functions that I have tried so far have allowed me to only consider each row individually (as opposed to the entire column). Below I have included the general structure of my approach.

```
data %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(missing_col = select_if(function(x) ... )) %>%
  names()
```

Any guidance toward the appropriate function would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> data %>% 
+   mutate(missing_col = apply(., 1, function(x) which(is.na(x)))  %>% 
+            map_chr(., function(x) if_else(length(x)==0, 
+                                           "NA", 
+                                           paste(names(x), collapse=", "))))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  var_1 var_2 var_3 missing_col 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
1    NA     4    NA var_1, var_3
2     4     5    NA var_3       
3     5     6    NA var_3       
4     6     7     3 NA          
5     7     8     5 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
#Unlist the results from apply
missing_col=unlist(x=apply(X=data, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x){

  #Get the names of the rows which have NA
  NamesNA=names(which(is.na(x)))

  #If there's no NA then replace the 'character(0)' for NA.
  if(length(NamesNA)!=0){

    #Concatenate names if there are more than one
    paste0(NamesNA, collapse=",")

  }else{

    #Replace 'character(0)'
    NA  

  }
})
)

#Add column with desired output
data$missing_col=missing_col
```

This give the desired output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  var_1 var_2 var_3 missing_col
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
1    NA     4    NA var_1,var_3
2     4     5    NA var_3      
3     5     6    NA var_3      
4     6     7     3 NA         
5     7     8     5 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a tidy way, but an apply seems to be simple enough:

```
data = tibble(var_1 = c(NA, 4, 5, 6, 7), var_2 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8), var_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 5))

data$missing = apply(data,1,function(x) names(x)[is.na(x)])
```

which outputs:

```
data
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  var_1 var_2 var_3 missing  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
1 NA     4.00 NA    <chr [2]>
2  4.00  5.00 NA    <chr [1]>
3  5.00  6.00 NA    <chr [1]>
4  6.00  7.00  3.00 <chr [0]>
5  7.00  8.00  5.00 <chr [0]>
```

So each element of the missing column is a list containing the character vector

```
data$missing[[1]]
[1] "var_1" "var_3"
data$missing[[1]][1]
[1] "var_1"
```

Comment: If I run that I end up with a tibble that doesn't display the actual column names in the new column -- just "<chr [2]>"

Comment: While it doesn't display the data when printed out you will be able to access each value in the missing column, whereas some other answers here are combining them into a single string, which will be hard to work with.

Comment: That's very helpful since I need the number of items. Thanks Leo!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use `apply` directly in mutate instead of `rowwise`. Perhaps an equivalent approach is possible with `rowwise`, but my experience with that function is limited. The second `mutate` is only necessary if you need `NA` for lines without `NA`.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(missing_col = apply(., 1, function(x) names(.)[is.na(x)] %>% paste(collapse = ", "))) %>% 
  mutate(missing_col = if_else(missing_col == "", NA_character_, missing_col))
```